# Excel Power Query Filtering by Cell Reference

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table named "TicketData" and it has many columns.  What I want to do is show a filtered view of this table in another table. I opened query editor and filtered everything down, except I have one additional filter needed and that is a date reference in a cell on another tab.  The other tab is named "ABN Chart".  I want that cell to filter the column named "Created Date".

Example
G5 in "ABN Chart" sets the filter of column 'TicketData'[Created Date] of the power query. I believe this can be done in the advanced query editor, but I don't know how. *I can change G5 to named reference if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I created another column in the original table called "InRange" and just pointed it to match the cell. This is the desired behavior.